# addView method does not display new view

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-framelayout

I want to add a new view to a `FrameLayout`, but it does only work "sometimes".
For example: I have set an `OnClickListener` to my layout (inside the onCreate-method of the activity) which adds a new view to the layout (this works). In the run-method of the activity i am using exactly the same code to add such a view, but the view does not show up. I don't know why...

Here is some code:

`OnClickListener`, which adds a new view to the layout and the view actually shows up. `layout` is the `FrameLayout`, `obstacles` is an object-list.

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        obstacles.add(new Obstacle(getBaseContext(), 0, (int) ((scale * 570) / 8), scale));
        layout.addView(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).view);

    }
});
```

if statement IS true, the new view is not being displayed, but the size of obstacles and the layout's childcount increase both by 1

```
if(checkForNew()){
    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(getBaseContext(), 0, (int) ((scale * 570) / 8), scale));
    layout.addView(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).view);
}
```

Constructor of `Obstacle`

```
public Obstacle(Context con, int left, int top, float scale) {
    view = new ImageView(con);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)(scale*150), (int)(scale*20));
    params.setMargins(left,top,0,0);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    view.setMaxWidth(view.getLayoutParams().width);
    view.setMaxHeight(view.getLayoutParams().height);
}
```

This is moving the views:

```
public void Move( View view, float speed, float scale){
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    params.setMargins(view.getLeft(), view.getTop() - (int) (scale * -speed), 0, 0);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: run-method of the activity???

Comment: @Msp i am using a runnable handler, which calls the method

Answer (score 1):

This is a `FrameLayout` and views will be *on top of each other*.

You do not seem to be changing the scale anywhere, and your margin is always fixed with `0, (scale * someValue)`

You need to apply a different scale and/or use different top/left parameters for the views you add.

Comment: they are not on top of each other. if i add views with the onclicklistener, the are placed with a topmargin of (570*scale)/8 so if i move those views and click, i can see the new view right at this position.
but in the if-statement, the new view is not being placed at this desired position

Comment: @purpule yes, I see that. But where do you modify this scale? if you add all the views with the same scale, they *will* be on top of each other

Comment: the scale is not being modified. it is my screen scale (scale=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;), so i don't have to operate with absolute pixels

Comment: @purpule So you add all your views to the same position `(x, y)` - they are drawn on top of each other

Comment: yeah, but while i draw the views to this position, i move the other views. so i actually would be able to see the new views but i dont, so i am confused

Comment: @purpule you should include the code where you move your other views in your question

Comment: @purpule also there is tools like the [HierarchyViewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) where you can check your layout

Comment: i updated the question, you can take a look if you want.

Comment: @purpule Looks normal. You should also provide the code how you call `Move`

Comment: this is called by microphone input. its definitely being called. i can see the first view moving.
furthermore adding the view works by clicking on the framelayout but not in the if statement. but why should it not work there?